# Inner shadow in UITextField with rounded corners

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, shadow

I want to implement this `UITextField` design:

[image]

In Zeplin here is the properties of the shadow:

[image]

What I have tried ?

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height/2
    self.addInnerShadow()
}


private func addInnerShadow() {
    let innerShadow = CALayer()
    innerShadow.frame = bounds
    // Shadow path (1pt ring around bounds)
    let path = UIBezierPath(rect: innerShadow.bounds.insetBy(dx: -1, dy: -1))
    let cutout = UIBezierPath(rect: innerShadow.bounds).reversing()
    path.append(cutout)
    innerShadow.shadowPath = path.cgPath
    innerShadow.masksToBounds = true
    // Shadow properties
    innerShadow.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    innerShadow.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
    innerShadow.shadowOpacity = 0.05
    innerShadow.shadowRadius = 3
    innerShadow.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height/2
    layer.addSublayer(innerShadow)
}
```

result:

[image]

Update:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
     super.layoutSubviews()
     self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height/2
     self.addInnerShadow()
 }


private func addInnerShadow() {
    let innerShadow = CALayer()
    innerShadow.frame = bounds
    // Shadow path (1pt ring around bounds)
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: innerShadow.bounds.insetBy(dx: -1, dy: -1), cornerRadius: self.frame.size.height/2)
    let cutout = UIBezierPath(rect: innerShadow.bounds).reversing()
    path.append(cutout)
    innerShadow.shadowPath = path.cgPath
    innerShadow.masksToBounds = true
    // Shadow properties
    innerShadow.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    innerShadow.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
    innerShadow.shadowOpacity = 0.05
    innerShadow.shadowRadius = 3
    //innerShadow.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height/2
    layer.addSublayer(innerShadow)
}
```

result:

[image]

the corner radius is causing a problem because the path is still rectangular and the shadow looks different

Comment: Setting `cornerRadius` on a layer with a shadow won't work. You have to create your path accordingly instead: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624356-init

Comment: @DavidGanster I have tried it but it does not work

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Reproducing an inner shadow to look exactly like the sketch equivalent is very difficult (I would suggest using a stretchable image), but using a rounded path for the shadow definitely works.

Comment: @DavidGanster check my update

Comment: Your cutout seems to be the opposite of what you want - only the corners have a shadow instead of everything else.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just use a rounded rect path:

```
private func addInnerShadow() {
    let innerShadow = CALayer()
    innerShadow.frame = bounds
    
    // Shadow path (1pt ring around bounds)
    let radius = self.frame.size.height/2
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: innerShadow.bounds.insetBy(dx: -1, dy:-1), cornerRadius:radius)
    let cutout = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: innerShadow.bounds, cornerRadius:radius).reversing()
    
    
    path.append(cutout)
    innerShadow.shadowPath = path.cgPath
    innerShadow.masksToBounds = true
    // Shadow properties
    innerShadow.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    innerShadow.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
    innerShadow.shadowOpacity = 0.15
    innerShadow.shadowRadius = 3
    innerShadow.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height/2
    layer.addSublayer(innerShadow)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To attain this - I added a uiimageview and input the image as the shadow text cell, then placed a label on top of the uiimageview with a clear background so you are able to see the shadow image through the text. This was all done with storyboard so I have no code to show and am not allowed to upload an image yet. Hope this helps.

Comment: Please share the code or more explanation. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your suggestion

Comment: K hope that makes sense