# Custom rounded Textfield with inner shadows does not get a correct layout

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, calayer, uibezierpath

I want to make a textfield that has inset shadows.

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47791243/10847224) but i do not get the expected result so because i don't have enough karma and cannot post a comment.

This is the result i get :

[image]

This is the code :

```
func applyDesign() {

    let innerShadow = CALayer()
    innerShadow.frame = bounds

    // Shadow path (1pt ring around bounds)
    let radius = self.frame.size.height/2
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: innerShadow.bounds.insetBy(dx: -1, dy:-1), cornerRadius:radius)
    let cutout = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: innerShadow.bounds, cornerRadius:radius).reversing()


    path.append(cutout)
    innerShadow.shadowPath = path.cgPath
    innerShadow.masksToBounds = true
    // Shadow properties
    innerShadow.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    innerShadow.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
    innerShadow.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    innerShadow.shadowRadius = 2
    innerShadow.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height/2
    layer.addSublayer(innerShadow)
}
```

How do i edit the code so that the textfield scales over the screen correctly again ?

Comment: I guess that the issue is that you call that method too soon. Your constraints haven't been applied yet, so the `bounds` you use aren't not the final one. You need to wait for the didLayoutSubviews (or something like that) to be called first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key thing is where do you call applyDesign. When view is loaded, it usually has size derived from nib / init method. So if you apply design then, it might not match what's on the screen later.

In your case, **you should reapply these custom design every time text field is layouted by auto-layout engine**.

Short example how could it look:

```
class CustomField: UITextField {

    lazy var innerShadow: CALayer = {
        let innerShadow = CALayer()
        layer.addSublayer(innerShadow)
        return innerShadow
    }()

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        applyDesign()
    }

    func applyDesign() {
        innerShadow.frame = bounds

        // Shadow path (1pt ring around bounds)
        let radius = self.frame.size.height/2
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: innerShadow.bounds.insetBy(dx: -1, dy:-1), cornerRadius:radius)
        let cutout = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: innerShadow.bounds, cornerRadius:radius).reversing()


        path.append(cutout)
        innerShadow.shadowPath = path.cgPath
        innerShadow.masksToBounds = true
        // Shadow properties
        innerShadow.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        innerShadow.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
        innerShadow.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        innerShadow.shadowRadius = 2
        innerShadow.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height/2
    }
}
```

You can improve it a bit by moving some redundant setup from `applyDeisgn` to some kind of one-time initializer (even in this lazy var definition).